# How to override the Kafka Topic configurations in MongoDB Source Connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using MongoDB Source Connector to get the data from a MongoDB collection into Kafka. What this connector does is that it automatically creates a topic using the following naming convention:

*[prefix_provided_in_the_connector_properties].[db_name].[collection_name]*

In the [MongoDB Source Connector's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-source/), there is no mention of overriding the topic configuration such as **number of partitions** or **replication factor**. I have the following questions:

> 1. Is it possible to override the topic configs in the connector.properties file?
> 2. If not, is it then done on Kafka's end? If so, can we individually configure each topics' settings or it will globally affect all the topics?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have `auto.create.topics.enable=true` on your brokers. It is recommended to disable this and enforce manual topic creation.

Connect only creates internal topics for itself. Source connectors should *ideally* have their topics created ahead of time, otherwise, you get the defaults set in the *broker* `server.properties`. Changing the values will not change existing topics